# Modify Azure cognitive search index

Tags: azure, api, azure-cognitive-search

My goal is to add a search bar in my website powered by azure cognitive search. Currently I have a pipeline that updates a storage blob container with the most recent version of the HTML files for my website. Currently when I call the api with a search word it returns a number of results(varies depending what word I use) and I am returned a search score but no data otherwise. The only lead I got was this forum ([Indexing HTML content from Azure database with Azure Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616430/indexing-html-content-from-azure-database-with-azure-search)) and when I attempt to add the parameters as shown in the response by Piotr Perak I noticed that any changes I make to the JSON form disappears after it is saved and reopened. In addition there is no way to modify the JSON on creation, so I seem to be quite stuck.

Basically the search should return the paragraph or title where the search word is found in the website along with a link for where it is located.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SDK to submit content to your index instead of using a built-in indexer. Then you create objects with the properties you want (title, body, url, ...) and submit to the index.

The response you get back will correspond to your data model.

Note: If you use a built-in indexer to index blobs from blob storage, the indexer cannot know how you want to organize your content. It cannot know that your files are HTML files or how you want to map the contents to a data model.